# border-spacing issue with span element

Tags: javascript, html, css, handlebars.js

How can i add space between this borders? Border-spacing is not working.

[image: Borders]

```
 {{#each spacing}}
<span class='space'>
  {{business}} ({{Count}})
</span>
{{/each}}
```

CSS

```
.space{
  border: 1px solid gray;
 border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

Comment: `border-spacing` is for table cells. You can use margin to separate them.

Comment: [`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) only applies to table cells which are not collapsing / separate.

Comment: please add `margin-left` to class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `margin` instead

```
.space {
 border: 1px solid gray;
 margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### border-spacing

[`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) only applies to table cells. If you want to use your `span` with that specific style property you have to set its parent display to `table` and the `span` itself to `table-cell`.

```css
div{
  border-spacing: 10px;
  display: table
}

span{
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table-cell
}
```

```html
  <div>
    <span>a</span>
    <span>b</span>
  </div>
```

### margin

Another way would be to add a [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin). Yet be aware of the excess margin on the last element, which might not always be desired.

```css
.spacer{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

/*REM: Remove margin on last element*/
.spacer:last-of-type{
  margin-right: 0
}
```

```html
<span class = 'spacer'>a</span>
<span class = 'spacer'>b</span>
<b>c</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

border-spacing only sets the distance between the borders of adjacent cells in a . You don't have a table here, so the command doesn't work!
You need to set the padding.
In your case: `padding: 10px;`

Comment: Is there another way I can add space between?

Comment: you have to set the padding: 10px;

Comment: Be aware that `border-spacing` is not limited to the tag `table`.

Comment: I tried that but it did not work.